# How do I ensure a VPN is always used?

Tags: linux, networking, macos, vpn, network-interface

I'm running a VPN and wonder what happens if the VPN connection breaks.

When I run `ifconfig` i see my default ethernet adapter at `en0` and the VPN at `utun0`. All traffic is running through the `utun0` interface.

1. Who defines that everything is running via `utun0` and not on `en0`? I know that my VPN provider software does that, via some DNS entries, but I do not get the entire concept.
2. If the VPN connection closes, `en0` takes over again. How can I prevent that from happening? E.g. can temporarily deactivate the `en0` or what steps would I have to take in order to prevent the IP Adress from leaking in case the connection accidentally breaks?

I'm interested in the general concept, hence I'm asking for osx and linux. It may be that I have misunderstood some basic concepts.

Comment: I'm not even close to an expert but the VPN I use times out either without activity, my home router closing the session, or the server timing it out for inactivity.  I'm just saying it may not be a local issue.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your VPN provider's SW (local client for you) will set up the routing tables accordingly. There's no way to determine routes by means of DNS as you seem to think. To avoid traffic when the VPN is down, you may have to stop using your VPN provider's VPN client. I suggest you do some Linux specific search on that, because you're not the first one who asks this.

Comment: Which kind of VPN are you using? Your answer depends on this.

Answer (score 1):

> Who defines that everything is running via utun0 and not on en0? I know that my VPN provider software does that, via some DNS entries, but I do not get the entire concept.

This is going to be the routing tables. These basically define which gateway will get you to which networks. On OS X the L2TP and PPTP VPNs using the built-in `racoon` daemon have an option under `System Preferences > Network > (VPN interface) > Advanced > Options` called "Send all traffic over VPN connection" that does this for you.

You could use `ipconfig route` yourself on both Linux and OS X.

> If the VPN connection closes, en0 takes over again. How can I prevent that from happening? E.g. can temporarily deactivate the en0 or what steps would I have to take in order to prevent the IP Adress from leaking in case the connection accidentally breaks?

1. You could hook into something that triggers when the network configuration changes (when the VPN fails, or interface goes away). On OS X you could create a launchd daemon that runs a script upon that event. The script should try to get the VPN back up else break the Internet. Here's an [example gist I found on github](https://gist.github.com/prehensile/675916) as to how to do that on OS X. Should be a way to assign a interface "down" script on Linux or do this directly in OpenVPN.
2. As a possibly more resilient solution you could make some firewall rules to only allow traffic over the VPN, with an exception for the VPN itself which must go out your actual interface.

If very worried about leakage VPN software vendors I believe would make a driver to do this a bit more robustly on OS X to ensure no packets ever escape if not over the VPN.